# Logic Evaluator in c# (Evaluate Logical (&& ,|| ) expressions)

Tags: c#, linq, boolean-logic, logical-operators, dynamic-linq

In my project there is a `Logic evaluation` section, it take input as a string which contains `logical expressions` (`true/false`) .

I want to evaluate this string and return a final Boolean value.

```
string Logic="1&0|1&(0&1)"
//string Logic="true AND false OR true AND (false AND true)"
```

This will be my `Logic`. The length might increase.

Is there any way to Evaluate this expression from `LINQ / Dynamic LINQ` ?

Comment: language integrated query != lexical parsing/evaluation

Comment: Any reason you're using a single bitwise AND but a short-circuiting logical OR in the example?

Comment: @ Kieren Johnstone : Oh sorry .. nothing like that... I will edit it.. :)

Comment: If it is okay to use a librarie take a look [here](https://github.com/Genfood/Proviant).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

a way without any third party libraries is to use a DataTable with expression.

There you have even the possibility to evaluate on other result value types than just boolean.

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("", typeof(Boolean));
table.Columns[0].Expression = "true and false or true";

System.Data.DataRow r = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.Add(r);
Boolean result = (Boolean)r[0];
```

the expression syntax is not identical with your example but it does the same thing. An advantage is that its 100% .NET framework contained --> Microsoft managed. 
The error handling is not bad neither. Exceptions for missing operators etc...

[available operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: but this is taking 7 milli seconds... my existing code takes less than 1 milli sec.... i want to reduce this

Comment: i dont think its the most performant option... but has quite some possibilities

Answer (score 13):

This is even shorter than the solution given by @fixagon:

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
bool result = (bool)table.Compute("true and false or true", "");
```

> `True`, `False`, `Not` operators, as well as parentheses are allowed.

Comment: Works for me (upvote). As an addition: also parentheses are allowed in order to change precedence.